# Version Management for shared webspace

Tags: svn

We use a simple shared webhosting provider but now I want to use version management on the uploaded files.

I tried Tortoise SVN and PHProjekt but they both only use offline files
Is there a program of online tool that keeps track of version-history on online files with ftp of something?

Doesn't have to be free but would be better ofcource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We use a simple shared webhosting provider but now I want to use version management on the uploaded files.

If you're talking about *code*, having version control on a shared web space usually not really an option, and it is also not the best way to go. 
You'll find that the most common pattern that is being used in web site projects is a deployment-based one, meaning

- People work on their local code base
- Changes are checked into a SVN repository (locally hosted or with an on-line service like [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com))
- Changes are checked out from the repository, and deployed to the web site, often using FTP, often using an automated script

this saves you the mess of having version controlled stuff online - what goes online is a cleaned-up, defined revision in the SVN repository.

I've tried building versioning and deployment on shared hosting several times, and my finding what there's no clean way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but we are with only 2 developers and it is just to much of a hassle to work offline and then upload a checked file afterwards. We only have one project, it is just meant to keep track of what is changed in what period of time, is there an other product that just does that?

Comment: @Luc you could have a SVN working copy online, but you'd need SVN on the server for that and check in the changes on the server afterwards. I can think of no way to do what you want on shared hosting...

Comment: @Luc you're welcome. You could theoretically connect to your web space using a product like FTPDrive, making it a Windows drive letter. You could then have a working copy on that remote drive. But that's bound to cause trouble when more than one person access it, plus unless you check in *every* change, you're still going to overwrite each other's work. Having a proper external repo is the best way to go IMO, I think I've seen online services that even offer automated deployment when you check in new stuff (probably not for free though)